# Unity with Google Play Plugin Application Freeze On Quit Application On Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services, unityscript, google-play-games

I am using unity 4.6.1 (Latest one) with Google Admob plugin and google play services plugin (I use only login/logout feature of the plugin for now).

The problem is the following. When I run my game on android and play return button, game freezes for around 10 seconds and then exit. However, when I disable login/logout, it exits as it should be. Some guys on forums talks about Admob for this problem, but Admob is so good so far and seems not causing this. The problem seems to be caused by login/logout. Any help?

Edit: When you never login in the game, the freeze problem doesn't appear. However, once you logged in and then logged out, it freezes on exit..

Comment: Anyone who face that problem also? https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/370

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround i put the following in my singleton:

```
public static void RealApplicationQuit()
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    ((GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).SignOut();
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
    AndroidJavaObject activity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"); 
    activity.Call<bool>("moveTaskToBack" , true);
    #endif
    Application.Quit();
}
```